# Python - argument passed through lambda function not retaining its state

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I have an module that produces the following form (using Python Tkinter):

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the form could have three states:

- Uneditable - entry boxes are disabled - Cancel and Edit button active
- Editable with no changes - entry boxes are active, Cancel button and
  the Edit button becomes a disabled Save button and
- Editable with changes - entry boxes are active, Cancel button becomes a revert button and the Save button becomes active

My code used to achieve this is as follows:

```
def display_selected_user(event, user_frame, editable):

    def fill_entry_boxes():
        # Clear entry boxes
        f_name.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        l_name.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        email.entry.delete(0, 'end')

        # Populate with original data
        f_name.entry.insert(0, user_dict[user_id]['f_name'])
        l_name.entry.insert(0, user_dict[user_id]['l_name'])
        email.entry.insert(0, user_dict[user_id]['email'])

        cancel_btn.config(text="Cancel")

    def cancel_revert_process():
        if not changes_made():
            user_detail_frame.grid_forget()
            close_btn.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='E')
        else:
            MsgBox = messagebox.askquestion('Revert Changes',
                                            f'Changes have been made - are you sure you want to revert?',
                                            icon='question')
            if MsgBox == 'yes':
                fill_entry_boxes()
                edit_save_btn.config(state='disabled', bg='gray80')

    def save_or_edit(event, _editable):
        if _editable:
            save_process(_editable)
        else:
            make_editable_process(_editable)

    def save_process(_editable):
        # Notify user of process commencement
        user_frame_messenger = MessageBox(user_frame, "")
        user_frame_messenger.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')
        user_frame_messenger.update_content(user_frame, "Saving user changes to database - one moment")
        # Save Process
        changes = record_changes()
        client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://xxxxxx.zzyri.mongodb.net/test?')
        db = client['football_data']
        collection = db['users']
        for key in changes[1]:
            collection.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(changes[0])},
                                  {"$set": {key: changes[1][key]}}
                                  )
        # Notify user of process completion
        user_frame_messenger.destroy()
        messagebox.showinfo("User detail updated",
                            "The changes to the user details have been saved")
        user_frame.grid_forget()
        cancel_revert_process()
        _editable = False

    def make_editable_process(_editable):

        f_name.entry.config(state='normal')
        l_name.entry.config(state='normal')
        email.entry.config(state='normal')
        _editable = True
        edit_save_btn.config(text="Save", state='disabled', bg='gray80')

    def key_pressed(event):
        if changes_made():
            cancel_btn.config(text="Revert")
            edit_save_btn.config(state='normal', bg="#43E082")
        else:
            cancel_btn.config(text="Cancel")
            edit_save_btn.config(state='disabled', bg='gray80')

    # Record data of selected user
    user = user_lst.tree.focus()
    user_data = user_lst.tree.item(user)
    user_id = user_data['values'][0]

    # Create objects
    f_name = LabelEntryCombo(user_frame, "First name:")
    l_name = LabelEntryCombo(user_frame, "Last name:")
    email = LabelEntryCombo(user_frame, "Email:")
    cancel_btn = ColourSchemedButton(user_frame, "PaleGreen", "Cancel")
    edit_save_btn = ColourSchemedButton(user_frame, "GreenBlue", "Edit", state='normal')

    # Fill entry boxes
    fill_entry_boxes()

    # Bind objects
    f_name.entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: key_pressed(e))
    l_name.entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: key_pressed(e))
    email.entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: key_pressed(e))
    cancel_btn.config(command=cancel_revert_process)
    edit_save_btn.config(command=lambda e=event, d=editable: save_or_edit(e, d))

    # Place and removal of objects
    close_btn.grid_forget()
    user_detail_frame.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NW')
    f_name.frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=10)
    l_name.frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=10)
    email.frame.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=10)
    cancel_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
    edit_save_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)

    # Configure grid
    user_detail_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    user_detail_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
    user_detail_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

    # Set state of  objects
    f_name.entry.config(state='disabled')
    l_name.entry.config(state='disabled')
    email.entry.config(state='disabled')
```

As you may pick up - I bind `save_edit_btn` with the following config using a lambda function which passes the `editable` variable used as a state handler `edit_save_btn.config(command=lambda e=event, d=editable: save_or_edit(e, d))`

That `editable` variable is initalisated outside this function as False and passed to the function `display_selected_user()` (A callback function from the main programme if you will) at the very top. So when the `save_edit_btn` is pressed the function makes the entries active and changes the other widgets accordingly (as per function  `make_editable_process()`) and changes the `editable` variable to True (even in the main program where it was initilised)

Problem is that after that the process goes back to the lambda line and resets the `editable` variable back to False - I don't understand why - and as a result the `save_process()` can never be initalised.

Any ideas on why this is the case will be appreciated - please let me know if you require any more code or detail.

Comment: There is a lot of unrunnable code for us to look here, but `_editable` is not `global` meaning, its value will be same only inside the function. So unless you pass the changed value into new function, the value should be taken as whatever is inside the function already. Or use `global _editable`.

Comment: any change you do to a local variable, like `_editable` in `make_editable_process`, is only visible inside that function, so see that change outside, you need to either return it, save into some external to the function given mutable object (like those various button thing), or declare it as either `global` or [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

Comment: (1) `_editable` is local variable and it will not change external variable - even with the same name. (2) for values like `True/False`, numbers, strings it sends its value to function (or other variable) - not reference to variable - so `a = False`, `_editable = a` , `_editable = True`, `print(a)` and `a` is still `False`, not `True`. You would have to use ie `tkinter.BooleanVar()` for this. `a = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)`, `_editable = a` , `_editable.set(True)`, `print(a.get())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For values like `True/False`, numbers, strings Python sends its value to function (or other variable) - not reference to variable.

For example:

```
 a = False 
 _editable = a 
 _editable = True
 print(a)
```

and `a` is still `False`, not `True`.

In `tkinter` you would use `tkinter.BooleanVar()` for this.

```
 import tkinter as tk

 a = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
 # a.set(False)
 _editable = a 
 _editable.set(True)
 print(a.get())
```

and nowe `a` changes value when you change `_editable`

Remeber to use `.get()` to get value, and `.set()` instead of `=` to set value.

---

**EDIT:**

In other situations you would have to use `return` and assign result back to variable

```
def function(_editable):
    # ... code ...

    _editable = True

    return _editable

a = False
a = function(a)  # assign returned value to `a`
print(a)
```

but when function is assigned to `Button` (or in `bind()`, or `after()`) then it can't get returned value and assign back to variable - and then usually we use `global` to assing value directly to external variable

```
def function(_editable):
    global a

    # ... code ...

    _editable = True
    a = _editable


a = False
function(a)  # without assignig returned value 
print(a)
```

Comment: "For values like True/False, numbers, strings Python sends its value to function" There is no difference in the semantics of passing between different types. The same syntax will produce the same semantics, always.

Answer (score 1):

Any change you do to a local variable, like _editable in make_editable_process, is only visible inside that function, so see that change outside, you need to either return it, save into some external to the function given mutable object (like those various button thing), or declare it as either `global` or [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

For your case I think the nonlocal would suffice.

example

what you're experimenting is this

```
>>> def fun():
        a=5
        def f():
            a=42
        print(a)
        f()
        print(a)


>>> fun()
5
5
>>>
```

`a` in `f` is a local variable to f, any change to it is only visible inside, to change it outside do any of previously mentioned methods, for example with nonlocal:

```
>>> def fun2():
        a=5
        def f():
            nonlocal a
            a=42
        print(a)
        f()
        print(a)


>>> fun2()
5
42
>>>
```